# spring 4 and CSRF

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I use spring boot, spring rest and spring security in a single page application.

With spring 4, CSRF is enable by default.

I wrote a class who extend WebSecurityConfigureAdapter

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();

      http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
      http.formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
      http.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
      http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    // tried with and without... same issue
      http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

}
```

CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter come from
https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/allanditzel/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java

I use only html (so no jsp, no xhmtl...) page only. 
I do ajax call and feed my html.

Request header

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 30
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: JSESSIONID=B05ED2676EC1637D74AC7622E018C9FD
```

In my form i have

```
 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

When I try to log, i get

```
{"timestamp":1444179957867,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?","path":"/login"}
```

When the log fail, this command return null

```
jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN')
```

ajax call

```
var data = 'username=' + $('#username').val() + '&password=' +  $('#password').val();
  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    timeout: 1000,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/login'
  }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     window.location = "main.html";
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

In the browser when i connect to localhost:8080.

i see in the header answer

```
X-CSRF-HEADER:X-CSRF-TOKEN
X-CSRF-PARAM:_csrf
X-CSRF-TOKEN:0d5bf042-a30f-4f2e-a99c-51ed512f811a
```

How to get this information in JS? I need to put it in my post call.

Comment: show us the HTTP request pls

Comment: You aren't sending the csrf parameter in the post

Comment: what i suppose to put there?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to debug this issue. You should post the following information:

1. Your XML/Java Spring Security Configuration.
2. Your Spring Web Configuration. Are you using JSPs or XHTML? Are you sure your view model is correct? Maybe your having issues with the web module not sending the token.
3. The actual http request headers/body. Is the request actually correct or is spring just not picking up the token?